# deepdiff not calculating difference properly

Tags: deep-diff

so while i was working with deepdiff i am facing some issues . while it is working fine on all type of changes most of the time . but some times it is giving an in correct difference . mostly when
the attribute.

```
ignore_order= True
```

but this is a necessary attribute .
it is not reading the json json properly . and mixing up the object as the json is very nested .

i tried checking on what kind of difference it is giving an error but it is pretty unclear as even for the same type of changes it is working fine most of the time . and the error is occuring at pretty random places.